# Integration of Brownian Motion with a function of t

Tags: brownian-motion

What would be integration of Brownian Motion with $t$ and is there a general formula for $f(t)$ , i.e.

1. What is $E[\int_{0}^{t}  t W_t dt]$? Is it $0$?
2. Any general rule or result for  $E[\int_{0}^{t}  f(t) W_t dt]$?

Comment: for example, if $f$ is continuous, denote by $F$ its anti-derivative. Then apply Ito formula to $F(t)W_t$, we can get $$F(t)W_t - F(0)W_0 - \int_0^t F(s) dW_s = \int_0^t  f(s) W_s ds $$  is this enough for your application ? p.s. the integral in your first point is not zero.

Comment: You are right! I forgot to add the expectation

Comment: Ok, then you can see from the above formula, the expectation that you want is equal to $$\mathbb{E}\left[ \,\, -\int_0^t F_s \, dW_s \,\, \right] . $$To answer your first question: yes. To answer your second question: if $f$ is continuous, then $F$ is differentiable (continuous), therefore $$t\geq 0 \longmapsto \int_0^t F_s \, dW_s   $$ defines a square-integrable martingale ==> Zero expectation. Of course you can weaken the assumption on $f$ a little bit.